# Calling function from HTML to typescript not waited to finish

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, angular-promise

I have an HTML element as bellow

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <input type='number' [min]="getMinData(param1,param2)" />
</div>
```

inside ts file

```
 getMinData(rules: ConstraintRule[], id: string) {
    rules.forEach((rule) => {
      rule._metadata.productList.forEach((product: SProduct) => {
        product.OptionGroups.forEach((optionGroup: SProductOptionGroup) => {
          optionGroup.Options.forEach((option: SProductOptionComponent) => {
            if (option.ComponentProductId == id) {
              return option.MinQuantity;
            }
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Also, there's no any API call or any other thing, it's just filtration over the local data.

But, On HTML correct qty is not returned.

Comment: Array.forEach is not asynchronous, it is blocking. Your code has to wait for it to finish, that is not your issue.

Comment: @Alex
Well if I do console on the last statement, I get the correct value, but on the HTML side even if I print this I don't get any value.

Comment: @Alex Do you see any other issue?

Comment: You're not returning anything

Comment: @Alex, An update, that HTML element is inside *ngFor, will that impact? Updating my question with more details.

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković What do you mean? I do return value `return option.MinQuantity;`

Comment: I think you may have edited to include less details.

Comment: @Alex Some formatting issue which made HTML code hidden, anyways it's updated now.

Comment: That's just returning from the `forEach` loop, not the function. The function `getMinData` always returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return something for `getMinData` function.

Currently, you call `return option.MinQuantity;`, but it is result for an anonymous function - `(option: SProductOptionComponent) => {`.

If you just want to find the first `option.MinQuantity`, try this function:

```
getMinData(rules: ConstraintRule[], id: string) {
  let minQuantity = 0;

  rules.forEach((rule) => {
    rule._metadata.productList.forEach(({ OptionGroups }) => {
      OptionGroups.forEach(({ Options }) => {
        const foundOption = Options.find((o) => o.ComponentProductId === id);
        minQuantity = foundOption ? foundOption.MinQuantity : 0; // Default min value is 0
      });
    });
  });

  return minQuantity; // return value
}
```